# Moshe Rabbeinu and Bil'am - Last Words

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash, parashat-balak, bilam, pharaoh

Both Bil'am (by Balak) and Moshe (by Pharaoh) are told, Leave, never dare to come back. By Bil'am (Bamidbar 24:11)

> וְעַתָּ֖ה בְּרַח־לְךָ֣ אֶל־מְקוֹמֶ֑ךָ
> And now, **flee** to your
> place...

Moshe you know already (Shemos 10:28-29):

> וַיֹּֽאמֶר־ל֥וֹ פַרְעֹ֖ה לֵ֣ךְ מֵעָלָ֑י הִשָּׁ֣מֶר לְךָ֗ אַל־תֹּ֙סֶף֙
> רְא֣וֹת פָּנַ֔י כִּ֗י בְּי֛וֹם רְאֹתְךָ֥ פָנַ֖י תָּמֽוּת׃
> Pharaoh said to him, “Be gone from me! Take care not to see me again, for the
> moment you look upon my face you shall die.”
> וַיֹּ֥אמֶר מֹשֶׁ֖ה כֵּ֣ן
> דִּבַּ֑רְתָּ לֹא־אֹסִ֥ף ע֖וֹד רְא֥וֹת פָּנֶֽיךָ And Moses replied,
> “You have spoken rightly. I shall not see your face again!”

In both cases, they say something anyhow, just before they leave, that talks about the bad end result of that nation's conduct (and conflict with Israel).
What is the point of this? Are there other examples?